# PHP versions conflicting

Tags: php, symfony, plesk

I'm working on a Symfony 2.8.9 site, but it requires PHP 5.5 or higher. In Plesk 12.5 I have set the server to use 5.6 which is fine, but when I run the `composer install` command via ssh, I get the following message:

> - symfony/symfony v2.7.0 requires php >=5.3.9 -> your PHP version (5.3.3) does not satisfy that requirement.

So I typed `php -v` and receieve the following message:

> PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2016 20:33:53)

I'm not sure why it says 5.3.3 on command line even though it's set to 5.6 in Plesk, how can I get around this? I'm unable to run my composer updates and even attempting to clear the cache throws errors which I am certain pertains to the outdated version of PHP.

Comment: CLI and web-server may use different version of PHP. To make sure that you are using the same version of PHP try to use `phpinfo()` in webserver and see the path of `php.in` and follow the same process or use `php -i|grep 'php.ini'` in SSH to see the loaded `php.ini` in command line. They might be pointing to different `php.ini` in your case.

Comment: It's using the wrong one, I know - but I don't know how to make it use the one I specify in Plesk.

Comment: if you know that you have `php5.6` and you know its full path to executable then you can give a try `/path/to/php5.6 composer update` but I am not sure whether this will work or not.

Answer (score 2):

As you have a plesk server you have to use the correct php-cli binary yourself.

The installed php versions are located at `/opt/plesk/php` in your case:
`/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php`

If you are root of this server you can help yourself with a simple symlink:
`ln -s /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php-5.6`

then you can use `php-5.6 composer.phar`

if not, you have to use the full path, or add an alias to your .bashrc.

an alternative is to add the `--ignore-platform-reqs` to the composer call. in most cases it will work (the php requirement is just ignored) - if the composer skript itself uses some 5.6 specific syntax, this will not work of course.

EDIT: my plesk is running on Ubuntu 16.04 - so the system php is 5.5.9 already - which makes the `--ignore-platform-reqs` trick very usable. on 5.3.3 i think you will run in more trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Are there more versions of php on your server? It could be that the webserver uses one version, and the CLI uses another.

Try the command `which php` to see what gets called.

Comment: Better command is to use the `sudo update-alternatives --config php` if the server is `Ubuntu` based. It will list multiple versions of PHP installed and we can select the one that we wish to set to default.

Comment: I don't want to update anything though. I don't have the permission here to do that - I just want to make sure that the command line is implementing the 5.6 version